# Как вызвать функцию в сервисе AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой сервис:

```
.service('socketNotifications', function(){

            var responseData = {};

            this.caseListen = function(type){
                switch(type){
                    case 'message':
                        alert(type);
                        break;
                }
            }

            this.listenSocket = function(){
                socket.on('message', function (response) {
                    responseData = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                    this.caseListen(responseData.type_item);
                });
            };
        })
```

В коллбеке socket пытаюсь вызвать метод из этого же сервиса:

```
this.caseListen(responseData.type_item);
```

Как вызывать методы внутри сервиса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` внутри обработчика `socket.on("message")` указывает на другой объект (this - это динамический контекст в JavaScript). Возможные решения вашей проблемы:

```
        var self = this; //сохраняем контекст в специальной переменной
        this.listenSocket = function(){
            socket.on('message', function (response) {
                responseData = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                self.caseListen(responseData.type_item); //используем эту переменную
            });
        };
```

или

```
        this.listenSocket = (function(){
            socket.on('message', (function (response) {
                responseData = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                this.caseListen(responseData.type_item);
            }).bind(this)); //привязываем контекст из родительской функции
        }).bind(this); //тут тоже
```